# Knockout component - Apply Binding Dynamically from Child ViewModel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, knockout-components

I have a `knockout component` which renders name of the Employees. In this component, I can pass `callback` function to change the format of the employee name displayed.

But I came into situation that I cannot change the component code. But I have to add Edit button to show modal popup to update the user information as shown in below image:

[image]

Some how I managed to display this Edit button using `callback` feature provided by component. But I am facing an issue with binding the `click event` of this button.

Issue is that: Even though I have defined callback function `ShowModal`, it is not getting called.

Here is my code:

**Component Registration:**

```
ko.components.register('emp-box', {
      viewModel: function(params) {
      var self = this;
      self.Name = ko.observable();
      self.Callback = params.formatCallback;

      if(self.Callback !== undefined)
      {
        self.Name(self.Callback(params.EmpName));
      }
      else
      {
        self.Name(params.EmpName.firstName + ', ' + params.EmpName.lastName);
      }

    },
    template: '<div class="name-container"><span data-bind="html: Name"></span></div>'
});
```

**ViewModel**

```
var vm = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.Emps = [{'Details': {firstName: 'First Name-A', lastName: 'Last Name-A'}},
                 {'Details': {firstName: 'First Name-B', lastName: 'Last Name-B'}}];

    // CALLBACK
    self.changeFormat = function(item)
    {
        return item.firstName + ' - ' + item.lastName + ' <span class="action" data-bind="click: ShowModal">Edit</span>';
    }

    self.ShowModal = function(item)
    {
        alert(1);
    }       
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

**HTML:**

```
<div data-bind='foreach: Emps'>
  <div data-bind='component: {
       name: "emp-box",
       params: {EmpName: Details, formatCallback: $root.changeFormat}
  }'></div>
</div>
```

**Working Fiddle:**  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dj396zaL/)

Comment: *"I am facing an issue"* - you forgot to describe your issue.

Comment: @Tomalak: Updated question. Issue is that callback function is not getting called.

Comment: The `formatCallback` function is getting called. The `ShowModal` function won't be called because you can't change the view by injecting some HMTL with `data-bind` attributes. Knockout binds your view *once*. When the `html` binding runs and changes the innerHTML of an element, binding is already finished. So what you try does not work the way you try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, you are trying to make the view dynamic by adding more "knockout code" through the `html` binding. This cannot work.

Before the `html` binding can even run, knockout must already have figured out the bindings, because how else would it know that it needs to run the `html` binding? And once the binding phase is done, it's done. Therefore you can't inject more knockout bindings that way.

Knockout views are flexible, just add all the parts you want them to have and display them dynamically. In this case you want to have an "Edit" button that shows up on demand. That's easy with the `if` binding:

```html
<div class="name-container">
    <span data-bind="text: displayName"></span>
    <span class="action" data-bind="if: canEdit, click: onEdit">Edit</span>
</div>
```

Now the viewmodel that controls this needs a `canEdit` value and an `onEdit` value, boolean and function respectively. These can be controlled through `params` during component binding.

When you make the displayName a computed and store the the name-formatting function in an observable, you can even switch the name format dynamically. Run the code sample below to see it in action.

```js
// emp-box.component.js ----------------------------------------------------
function standardNameFormat(emp) {
    return ko.unwrap(emp.lastName) + ', ' + ko.unwrap(emp.firstName);
}

ko.components.register('emp-box', {
    viewModel: function (params) {
        this.emp = params.emp;
        this.displayName = ko.computed(function () {
            var formatter = ko.unwrap(params.formatter) || standardNameFormat;
            return formatter(params.emp);
        });
        this.canEdit = params.canEdit;
        this.onEdit = params.onEdit;
    },
    template: '<div class="name-container">\
        <span data-bind="text: displayName"></span>\
        <span class="action" data-bind="if: canEdit, click: onEdit">Edit</span>\
    </div>'
});
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

function EmployeeList(params) {
    var self = this;
    self.emps = ko.observableArray(params.emps);
    self.canEdit = ko.observable(false);

    self.firstnameLastname = function (emp) {
        return ko.unwrap(emp.firstName) + ' ' + ko.unwrap(emp.lastName);
    };
    
    self.nameFormat = ko.observable(self.firstnameLastname);
    self.showModal = function () {
        alert("You clicked on " + ko.unwrap(this.displayName));
    };
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

ko.applyBindings(new EmployeeList({
    emps: [
        {firstName: 'First Name-A', lastName: 'Last Name-A'},
        {firstName: 'First Name-B', lastName: 'Last Name-B'}
    ]
}));
```

```css
.name-container{
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: #cacaca;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.name-container span {
  margin: 5px;
}

body {
  font-family: arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.action {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: canEdit" id="chkEdit">
<label for="chkEdit">Enable editing</label>

<input type="radio" data-bind="value: null, checked: nameFormat" id="chkFmt1">
<label for="chkFmt1">Default format</label>
<input type="radio" data-bind="value: firstnameLastname, checked: nameFormat" id="chkFmt2">
<label for="chkFmt2">Alternative format</label>

<div data-bind='foreach: emps'>
  <div data-bind='component: {
       name: "emp-box",
       params: {emp: $data, formatter: $root.nameFormat, canEdit: $root.canEdit, onEdit: $root.showModal}
  }'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wanted to achieve without modifying `component`. But as you said `Before the html binding can even run, knockout must already have figured out the bindings`, I totally agree with you. Thanks

Comment: That's just like SQL injection: *"I want the table name and the number of WHERE conditions to be user-configurable"* - That's hardly ever a good idea, and most of the time a sign of bad design. Think of a declarative way of expressing what you want, i.e. one that does not rely on code injection. For example, make separate components that all share a the same viewmodel but have different views. In the component binding [the `name` can be observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html#api). Switch the names to get different rendering views.